# bundle install --without production "gemfile:13: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I am learning RoR via The Odin Project.  Using Windows 8. I was able to do my first commit, however when I attempted a "bundle install _without production" I received the error in the question title.  In order to try and solve this error message, so far I have:

1. Edited the gemlock file per http://guides.railsgirls.com/openshift.  eg. change pg (0.16.0-x86-mingw32) to pg (0.16.0) and sqlite3 (1.3.8-x86-mingw32) to sqlite3 (1.3.8)).

So I DID delete  x86-mingw32 from  sqlite3 file, however I did NOT find "pg" in the gemlock file. So I could not edit it.  Gemlock file:

[image: first_gemlock file]
[image: 2nd_gemlock file]
[image: 3rd gemlock]
[image: gemlock]

The instructions I am following  at: 
http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/create_and_deploy_a_rails_app?back=create_a_heroku_account

at step 7.2 say that if I get this error:

"If this fails, get a volunteer to help you edit config/environments/production.rb"

so I opened up the "production.rb" file in Sublime Text 3, but didn't know what to edit by myself. ? I attached the screenshots of the production.rb file below:

1. Git 1.8.4mysygit.o
2. ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]
3. rails 4.0.2
4. sqlite3 (1.3.9)

[image: First_production.rb]
[image: second_production.rb]
[image: third_production.rb]
[image: preparing app to deploy to heroku step 7.2]

Here's the Gemfile: 
[image: 1Gemfile]
[image: 2gemfile]

Comment: can you post your Gemfile please? As an aside, you shouldn't really edit Gemfile.lock. Amend the gems (and gem versions as necessary) in the Gemfile and re-run bundle install. That'll re-create the Gemfile.lock file with updated versions/dependencies as specified in the Gemfile.

Comment: your seeing a simple syntax error, you are probably just missing an end in your code. Post your gemfile like Chris suggested, its probably in there.

Comment: You've posted your "Gemfile.lock" but the issue is in "Gemfile".

Comment: @ChrisLewis, and Matt oh ok I edited the question to include the gemfile. Thank you.

Comment: @MattRamirez hey thanks. Yeah I hope it's simple. I just haven't figured it out yet. I did post the "gemfile" though. Do you see the solution in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's on line 10 - remove the comma:

```
group :production do
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. That worked.  Next time I won't try to find a simple mistake at 2:30am.

Comment: Great! Could you mark it as the correct answer if it solved your issue please? Many thanks. Enjoy the rest of RoR - it's pretty awesome when you get into it...